# Using Vieta's formulae for the repeated composition of a quadratic function

Tags: functions, polynomials, quadratics, function-and-relation-composition

[image]

In the problem, it's clear that it is the four times repeated composition of the function $f(x) = (x+2)^2$ and that $15129$ is the square of $123$. So, as we work backward, we eventually go from $15129$ to $123$ to $11$ to $3$ to $1$ and every time (except the last time), we neglect the corresponding negative answer because there is a perfect square on the LHS. So, finally, the answer should be $+1$ and $-1$. However, upon plugging in $(+1)$ to verify the solution, it turns out to be extraneous. Why does this happen? Where do we gain this extra solution?

Also, is there a better way to solve this problem using Vieta's formula, which may be more generally applicable to this variety of problems where, there exists a polynomial that can be manipulated into the repeated composition of a certain quadratic, and hence its roots can be analyzed easily?

Comment: You have been around for more than a year. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: I'll do that next time, for certain

Comment: You just made a mistake in the last step, you should not get $x=\pm1$ but $2+x=\pm1$. That said, depending on how the problem is to be understood you should also think about the multiplicity of these two real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x+2)^2= t$, $(2+t)^2 = t_2$, $(2+t_2)^2=t_3$ etc.

Then you're given that $(2+t_3)^2=123^2$ and it follows that
$$(t_3+125)(t_3-121) =0$$
Then put the value $t_3$ and proceed:
$$((2+t_2)^2+125)((2+t_2)^2-11^2)=0$$
The first term gives a complex solution (since it means $(2+t_2)^2=-125$), so it is not necessary for us to consider it.

So if we proceed again by factoring using difference of squares we get
$$(t_2+13)(t_2-9)=0$$
Ignore the first term again and get:
$$(t+5)(t-1) =0$$
Ignore the complex solution, so that $t-1$ factors into
$$(x+3)(x+1)=0$$

These are the only real solutions. Then their sum is?